# Datatable scrollbar doesn't show up in IE

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I got a dataTable with scrollable and resizeableColumns set to true, and the scrollbar works perfectly in firefox and chrome, but in IE the scrollbar doesnt show up. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

```
<p:dataTable id="allTable" widgetVar="allTableW"
     emptyMessage="Keine Todos gefunden" var="currentTableItem"
     value="#{allTableController.dataModel}" paginator="true" rows="15"
     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20, 25, 30" lazy="false"
     paginatorPosition="bottom"
     currentPageReportTemplate="( Treffer {totalRecords} ) ( Seite {currentPage} von {totalPages} )"
     filteredValue="#{allTableController.filteredTodos}" filterDelay="500"
     filterEvent="keyup" editable="true"
     sortBy="#{currentTableItem.angelegtAm}" sortOrder="descending"
     selectionMode="single" selection="#{allTableController.selectedToDo}"
     scrollable="true" resizableColumns="true">

                   ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using IE9 then definitely there is a bug in IE9. I also faced these kind of thing in IE, so don't worry about it your code is ok.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I need a workaround, I need something, my customer uses IE 9 so he needs to see the scrollbar.